# Android Oreo Shared Preference returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es

Android Oreo has been returning me a null pointer exception. This started when i updated my gradle to ai.api:libai:1.6.11. Can anyone help me out. Because the same code works perfectly if I roll the gradle ai.api library back

Comment: can you please share gradle file.

Comment: please post the logs

Comment: can you please share the solution if u got any